# Google maps Polyline latitude 0, longitude 0 issue

Tags: google-maps, polyline, coords

I'm trying to display a tractor's route in google maps and having the following problem (I like to call it "The Guinea Problem":

http://i901.photobucket.com/albums/ac215/MigerusanTTE/coordserrorfinal.jpg

In the pic you can see that the starting point of my polyline starts from lat 0, long 0. I dont know why this is happening because on my while loop I put an alert when it starts and the latlng values are correct when it begins...

Here you have a portion of the code for markers and polylines:

```
    //If i==0 (my FOR variable for looping), coords_prev=coords.


    //alert(coords); //alert I put to see what was happening D:
    var marker    =  new google.maps.Marker(
    {
      position: coords,
      map: map,
      icon:direccion_ico
    });
    }

   //contructing the line

    var line = [coords_prev, coords];

    var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: line,
      strokeColor: color,
      strokeOpacity: 0.6,
      strokeWeight: 3
    });


    linesArray.push(polyline);
    polyline.setMap(map);
    coords_prev = coords;  //I equal these for the next loop
```

Tell me what you think...and If I forgot to mention something important too.

Answer (score 0):

On the line

```
   var line = [coords_prev, coords];
```

This is fine for the second point, but for the very first point, you won't have anything in coords_prev.  Thus, for the very first segment, it will start at 0,0 and go to coords.

Comment: Take a look to the first comment line in the code. If it's the start of loop (where i=0), i just take the same coords for both, coords and coords_prev, so they're the same point. So coords_prev is not empty, any ideas? Thanks for the help.

Comment: But that line is commented out.  Are you saying that coords_prev gets set to coords before this code executes?